# how can i add response of json.loads together

Tags: python, json, dictionary

i have

```
wordpress_version_dict,drupal_version_dict,ada_dict,ssl_dict,link_dict,tag_dict
```

which all are json.loads response now I want to add in  like

```
new_dict = wordpress_version_dict+drupal_version_dict+ada_dict+ssl_dict+link_dict+tag_dict
```

so that i can save the whole response in one filed of the database.

***any advice ??***

Answer (score 0):

If the question is how to pack several variables into one bigger one, then you could try and pack it into one `dict` and then `json.dumps` it into string field of the database

To collect several variables into dict I would use `locals`, especially since you stated the whole list

```
var_list = 'wordpress_version_dict,drupal_version_dict,ada_dict,ssl_dict,link_dict,tag_dict'
```

then 'parse' variable names into generator

```
collected = {var_name: locals()[var_name] for var_name in var_list.split(',')}
```

And `json.dumps(collected)` would be the string to store